# Hibernate DetachedCriteria null pointer for multiple detached queries (DetachedCriteria into DetachedCriteria)

Tags: java, hibernate, detachedcriteria

I'm trying to implement a DetachedCriteria, but running a subquery inside another DetachedCriteria error occurs.

I have already searched in several places but I have not found any examples where a detacehdCriteria.add (Subqueries.exists (otherDc)) is used. How should I proceed?

Thank you.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Fatura.class, "f");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("f.id.producao", codProd));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("f.situacaoFatura", "L"));

DetachedCriteria dcFaturaEmpresas = DetachedCriteria.forClass(FaturaEmpresa.class, "fe");
dcFaturaEmpresas.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("f.id.numeroFatura", "fe.id.numeroFatura"));
dcFaturaEmpresas.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("f.id.producao", "fe.id.producao"));
dcFaturaEmpresas.add(Restrictions.eq("fe.codEmpresa", codEmpresa));

criteria.add(Subqueries.exists(dcFaturaEmpresas));

DetachedCriteria dcFatura02 = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Fatura.class, "f02");
dcFatura02.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("f.id.producao", "f02.id.producao"));

DetachedCriteria dcFaturaEmpresas02 = DetachedCriteria.forClass(FaturaEmpresa.class, "fe02");
dcFaturaEmpresas02.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("f02.id.numeroFatura", "fe02.id.numeroFatura"));
dcFaturaEmpresas02.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("f02.id.producao", "fe02.id.producao"));
dcFaturaEmpresas02.add(Restrictions.eq("fe02.codEmpresa", codEmpresa));

dcFatura02.add(Subqueries.exists(dcFaturaEmpresas02)); //I think the error is here...

dcFatura02.setProjection(Projections.min("f02.dataVencimento"));

criteria.add(Subqueries.exists(dcFatura02));

listFaturas = (List<Fatura>) criteria.list();
```

Here with I've attached the Exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getProjectedTypes(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:382)
at org.hibernate.criterion.SubqueryExpression.createAndSetInnerQuery(SubqueryExpression.java:135)
at org.hibernate.criterion.SubqueryExpression.toSqlString(SubqueryExpression.java:61)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getWhereCondition(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:400)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:106)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:75)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.<init>(CriteriaLoader.java:80)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1760)
at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:363)
at br.com.emp.siscom.dao.FaturaDao.hasPrimeiraFaturaEmpresaPaga(FaturaDao.java:69)
at br.com.emp.siscom.controller.PagamentosAdicionais107.pagamentoBonificacaoVendaPjContratoSuperior1Vida(PagamentosAdicionais107.java:40)
at br.com.emp.siscom.controller.PagamentosAdicionais107.executarPagamentoBonificacaoPorData(PagamentosAdicionais107.java:114)
at br.com.emp.siscom.controller.PagamentosAdicionaisController.executarPagamentosAdicionais(PagamentosAdicionaisController.java:17)
at br.com.emp.siscom.managedbean.PagamentosAdicionaisBean.carregarPagamentosAdicionais(PagamentosAdicionaisBean.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:300)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:415)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:285)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
at br.com.emp.siscom.filtro.Filtro.doFilter(Filtro.java:66)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at br.com.emp.siscom.filtro.FiltroLocale.doFilter(FiltroLocale.java:41)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: rectification: 
in the line:
"criteria.add (Subqueries.exists(dcFatura02));" 
it reads: 
criteria.add (Subqueries.propertyEq (" f.dataVencimento ", dcFatura02));"